# Why Card.io is not working on Google nexus 5?

Tags: android, card.io

In my app, I am integration card.io sdk. I have successfully integrated it and it is working fine (in mentioned device Samsung S3,S4 mini and motorolla droid turbo). But when I tested on Google nexus5 the camera is not launched and on console log I can see below error
Processor not Supported. Skipping camera
Then I further explore Card.io sdk and I found that it worked on Supported processors as mentioned in SDK 'Neon, Tegra and x86'. Then I checked nexus 5 processor architecture it is x86 i guess.So what is the updated regarding this issue? Is there any alternate or some other help?Or is this limitation?

Comment: Nexus 5 is not x86 : http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_5-5705.php . Its CPU is Krait 400, which is an ARM architecture CPU.

Comment: Opppss sorry you are right it is ARM . I mistakenly typed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time, I found something that solved my problem. Now sharing my answer it may help others. Previously I was using Card.io SDK version '5.4.2' and I just changed SDK version to '5.4.1' and now it is working on ARM device (Nexus 5 ) as well. There may be some problem with SDK version of 5.4.2.